# What this parameter is responsible for? markerSpec in InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid by Appolica

Tags: google-maps-markers

in https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid i read that

> markerSpec - Provides the marker's offsetX and offsetY

but I can't understand what it is responsible for, I changed the values in every possible way, but the result was always the same. R.dimen.marker_offset_x =5dp R.dimen.marker_offset_y=39dp

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            final Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(1, 1)).snippet(FORM_VIEW));
            final int offsetX = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.marker_offset_x);
            final int offsetY = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.marker_offset_y);
            final InfoWindow.MarkerSpecification markerSpec =
                    new InfoWindow.MarkerSpecification(offsetX, offsetY);


            formWindow = new InfoWindow(marker2, markerSpec, new FormFragment());

            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        }
```

Maybe someone has worked with this and can explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was entering too large values

[image]
[image]